# A script to create new users with user input

Tags: bash, scripts

I need an automated script to create users which will be saved as an executable file on the desktop.

When running the script it needs to ask the user for a username and a password for that username.

Are there any resources where I can learn to write such scripts which execute pre-written commands and require prompts from the user as a previous Windows user without any programming skills?

Comment: What's wrong with adding users via *Settings* -> *Users*?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a script that invokes that `useradd` command for this. Something along the lines of

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Username:";
read USR;
echo "Password:";
read PWD;
HASHEDPWD = "$(python3 -c 'import crypt; print(crypt.crypt("'"$PWD"'"))')"
useradd -m -p $HASHEDPWD $USR && echo "Success";
```

note that this script would not work unless you are `root` since `useradd` requires root privileges to create directories in `/home/$USR` and also to modify `/etc/passwd` among other files

Shell scripts, such as this are stored as `.sh` files. So for instance, you'd save this as `makeuser.sh`. By default scripts are not given permission to execute, and you've to manually declare that by using `chmod +x makeuser.sh`

The first line (referred to as the shebang) determines the interpreter that the system will use to run the script. In this case, it runs it with the `bash` shell (Which is also default on ubuntu)

A good resource to learn more about bash would be [googling tutorials](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/) and for details on how to use a specific command, you can use the `man` command. For instance, if you wanted to know more on the flags and other arguments accepted by `useradd`, you could use `man useradd`